# Implementing a Database - Cannot read property 'initializedRelationships' of undefined - Ember js

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ember.js, emberfire

here is the adapter
In Ember Data, an Adapter determines how data is persisted to a backend data store. Things such as the backend host, URL format and headers used to talk to a REST API can all be configured in an adapter.

```js
/* adapters/application.js */

import FirebaseAdapter from "emberfire/adapters/firebase";

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({});
```

A Controller is routable object which receives a single property from the Route .. here is the controller

```js
/* controllers/cars.js */

import Controller from "@ember/controller";

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    deleteCar(id) {
      this.get("store")
        .findRecord("car", id, { reload: true })
        .then(car => {
          car.destroyRecord();
          car.save();
          //self.transitionToRoute("cars");
         });
    }
  }
});
```

```js
/* controllers/cars/edit.js */

import Controller from "@ember/controller";

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    editCar: function(id) {
      var self = this;
      var make = this.get("model.make");
      var model = this.get("model.model");
      var year = this.get("model.year");
      this.store.findRecord("car", id).then(function(car) {
        car.set("make", make);
        car.set("model", model);
        car.set("year", year);
        car.save();
        self.transitionToRoute("cars");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```js
/* controllers/cars/new.js */

import Controller from "@ember/controller";

export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    addCar: function() {
      var self = this;
      var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000 + 1);
      var newCar = this.store.createRecord("car", {
        id: rand,
        make: this.get("carMake"),
        model: this.get("carModel"),
        year: this.get("carYear")
      });
      newCar.save();
      self.transitionToRoute("cars");
    }
  }
});
```

In Ember Data, models are objects that represent the underlying data that your application presents to the user. Note that Ember Data models are a different concept than the model method on Routes, although they share the same name .. here is the model

```js
/* models/cars.js */

import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.Model.extend({
  make: DS.attr("string"),
  model: DS.attr("string"),
  year: DS.attr("string")
});
```

In Ember, when we want to make a new page that can be visited using a URL, we need to generate a "route" using Ember CLI .. here is the routes

```js
/* routes/cars.js */

import Route from "@ember/routing/route";

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll("car", {
      orderBy: "make"
    });
  }
});
```

```js
/* routes/cars/edit.js */

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({});
```

```js
/* routes/cars/new.js */

import Route from "@ember/routing/route";

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll("car");
  }
});
```

```js
/* routes/users.js*/

import Route from "@ember/routing/route";
import $ from "jquery";

export default Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var url = "https://api.github.com/users";
    return $.getJSON(url).then(function(data) {
      return data.splice(0, 10);
    });
  }
});
```

The EmberRouter class manages the application state and URLs .. here is the router

```js
/* router.js */

import EmberRouter from "@ember/routing/router";
import config from "./config/environment";

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.rootURL
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route("cars", function() {
    this.route("new");
    this.route("edit", { path: "/edit/:car_id" });
  });
  this.route("users");
});

export default Router;
```

A template is used to create a standard layout across multiple pages. When you change a template, the pages that are based on that template automatically get changed. Templates provide standardization controls.

```html
<!-- templates/users.hbs -->

<h1>Github Users</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each model as |user|}}
    <li>{{user.login}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

```html
<!-- templates/car.hbs -->

{{#link-to "cars.new"}}Create Car{{/link-to}}
<hr>
{{outlet}}
<h1>Cars</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each model as |car|}}
    <li>
      {{car.year}} {{car.make}} {{car.model}} -
      {{#link-to "cars.edit" car.id}}Edit{{/link-to}}
      <button {{action "deleteCar" car.id}}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

```html
<!-- templates/application.hbs -->

{{outlet}}
```

```html
<!-- templates/cars/new.hbs -->

<form {{action "addCar" on="submit"}}>
  <p>Make: {{input type="text" value=carMake}}</p>
  <p>Model: {{input type="text" value=carModel}}</p>
  <p>Year: {{input type="text" value=carYear}}</p>
  <p>{{input type="submit" value="submit"}}</p>
</form>
```

```html
<!-- templates/cars/edit.hbs -->

<form {{action "editCar" model.id on="submit"}}>
  <p>Make: {{input type="text" value=model.make}}</p>
  <p>Model: {{input type="text" value=model.model}}</p>
  <p>Year: {{input type="text" value=model.year}}</p>
  <p>{{input type="submit" value="Submit"}}</p>
</form>
```

run

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializedRelationships' of 
undefined
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Ax0.png
```

here is my app [drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16hyWS2RoQBElr2bPHsRpACMzB-PNUES_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Have you tried to build a MCVE instead of trying to paste your entire app? Can you build a reproduction with `ember-twiddle` or provide a git repo with reproduction?

Comment: No I did not try ember-twiddle, I checked it but don't know how to use it, you can check my post again I shared my app by google drive link

Comment: why you didn't give `apiKey`, `authDomain` and other configuration values in you `config/environment.js` ?

Comment: have you followed the basic startup guides for ember and firebase ?
https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/emberfire/docs/quickstart.md/

Comment: Yes I do, I added all the configuration values of the firebase DB, you can check my app here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fxapDuLVHbPmyIPQNuvXez_Mvv9dAjuY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you get the error if you remove the `model` hook? Could you verify if its a problem with the firebase adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error disappears when I `remove the findAll query inside model hook`. Probably this would be an error with firebase config.

You missed entering the below config. Make sure you have all these variables inside your `app/config/environment.js`

```
var ENV = {
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "your-api-key",
    authDomain: "YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "YOUR-FIREBASE-APP",
    storageBucket: "YOUR-FIREBASE-APP.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "00000000000"
  }
}
```

My app works fine with firebase. Please do follow the step by step approach from [here](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/emberfire/docs/quickstart.md/)

You have installed both stable and latest build versions of `emberfire`,

```
"emberfire": "^2.0.10",
"emberfire-exp": "^3.0.0-rc.1-4",
```

Which is not necessary. Install any one version.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ember-cli 3.12.0, when you are creating the firebase connection with your app by default "emberfire/adapters/firebase" will be imported automatical in adapters/application.js, **which is not true**.

```js
`/* adapters/application.js */

import FirebaseAdapter from "emberfire/adapters/firebase";

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({});`
```

**go there and edit that import to "emberfire/adapters/firestore"**.

```js
`import FirebaseAdapter from 'emberfire/adapters/firestore';

export default FirebaseAdapter.extend({

});`
```

and downgrade your "ember-source to : 3.10.0" in package.json